# Python error: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, syntax-error, operand

My code is supposed to read and subtract two data lists from each other. Why am I receiving this error, and how can I resolve it?

Here is the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "spectra.py", line 32, in SpectraTest
    subt = map(sub, flux, flux1)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'NoneType'
```

Here is the code:

```
import csv

def SpectraTest():
    wave_num = []
    flux = []
    wave_num1=[]
    flux1 = []
    with open ("H20_Glass.CSV", "rb") as csvfile:
        datareader= csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ",")
        for row in datareader:
            tempdata = row
            wn = tempdata[0]
            f1 = tempdata [1]
            wn = eval(wn)
            f1 = eval(f1)
            wave_num.append(wn)
            flux.append(f1)

    with open ("blankGlass.CSV", "rb") as csvfile:
        datareader= csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ",")
        for row in datareader:
            tempdata1 = row
            wn1 = tempdata1[0]
            f2 = tempdata1[1]
            wn1 = eval(wn1)
            f2 = eval(f2)
            wave_num1.append(wn1)
            flux1.append(f2)
        map(float, flux1)
        map(float, flux)
        from operator import sub
        subt = map(sub, flux, flux1)
        wave_num1.reverse()
        wave_num.reverse()
        print("Number of wave numbers " + str(len(wave_num1)))
        print("Number of flux numbers = "+ str(len(flux1)))

        print("Number of wave numbers " + str(len(wave_num)))
        print("Number of flux numbers = "+ str(len(flux)))
        print subt
    csvfile.close()
```

Comment: flux1 is probably `None`. Are you sure both elements have the same size and that flux1.append(f2) is being called?

Comment: `flux1` might not have any `None` values, if it is shorter than `flux`, `map` will extend it with `None`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Python docs:

> map(function, iterable, ...)
>
> ...If one iterable is shorter than another it is
>   assumed to be extended with None items...

I'd guess that your lists are not the same length so that it's trying to subtract a None from a float.

Comment: Thank you, I just realized that that was exactly what was happening.